# Why is local realism not possible with QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, non-locality

In Mermin's thought experiment ([pdf](http://hep.ucsb.edu/courses/ph125_02/mermin.pdf)) particles are sent to two detectors A and B with 3 settings each. If the particle passes the test, we get a green (G) light, else red (R).

Now in QM we could send entangled photons with opposite (90°) polarization to the machines, and each setting is a polarization filter with different angle. Obviously, a particle going through the filter would be a pass, or green.

Now the "problem" is that in this QM experiment we always see opposite results for same settings (11, 22, 33), but if we posit that the entangled photons have a static plan of passing vs. failing at each angle, we should see 4 same (RR, GG) and 5 different (RG, GR) results out of the 9 total combinations of settings.
However, in the QM experiment we see 50% same/different.

---

But why is this local "plan" supposed to be static? **Why doesn't this plan simply change for each entangled photon pair, to average to 50% same/different results?**

---

Why I don't agree with the conclusion that a violation of Bell's inequality proves non-locality:

Let's make a simple thought experiment. We have 3 settings, each is a polarization filter at angles 0°, α, 2α respectively.

Now we test and calculate `P(pass 0°, fail α) + P(pass α, fail 2α) >= P(pass α, fail 2α)`.

A randomly polarized particle has a probability of `1/2` to pass each of the first settings, and `sin(angle)^2` to fail the next setting after the first polarization filter is passed.

So we get: `1/2 sin(α)^2 + 1/2 sin(α)^2 >= 1/2 sin(2α)^2
given α=60°: 0.75 >= 0.375
given α=30°: 0.25 >= 0.375` ... violation

So the only reason there is a violation appears to be the nature of the probability of passing/failing a test, not the number of particles or their connection.

Comment: Is the question one of why Bell's theorem identifies differing results for the two case, or why people have concluded that Bell's inequality is violated?

Comment: @dmckee Neither. Bell's inequality is violated with just 1 particle in a QM thought experiment, because the probability to pass a polarization filter is not linear but cos(angle)^2 - so I don't see how this is even relevant for 2 entangled particles.

Comment: @dmckee I added a section on Bell's inequality. If you see an error in my thinking please let me know.

Comment: Bell's inequality is certainly not violated by one particle, because it explicitly talks about a pair of particles (I'm referring to the most common CHSH inequality). I have no idea what you are talking about, but it's not a Bell-inequality.

Comment: Violations of Bell's inequality don't prove non-locality as such. They prove that at least one of realism and locality fail. Many people are very firmly of the opinion that *obviously* one of them can't be violated so it must be the other that fails. Alas, not everyone agrees on the identity of the sacrosanct principle.

Comment: @Martin The basic idea of the inequality: http://oi57.tinypic.com/23ubssg.jpg

Comment: @dmckee So QM can be local, but why is realism rejected also? Just because we don't know some details about e.g. a photon does not mean that it doesn't have a pre-existing value e.g. for polarization.

Comment: The issue is not that we don't know details about a photon.  The issue is that Bell's inequality is violated.  But you will never understand this issue until you understand Bell's inequality, which (as is quite clear from your "one particle" example) you currently don't.

Comment: @xnor People use a straw man version of realism in order to formulate the kinds of locality they want to reject. The straw man realism they want is wrong and can be shown so for single particles.

Comment: @WillO See the image posted above. For the simplest case we just need to subject some x to 3 tests. It doesn't matter if x is 1 particle or 2 or 3, as long as they are "identical" (the tested property could also be opposite if we account for that in the tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is based on a certain kind of realism a kind of realism that is obviously wrong just for even just one unentangled particle. A kind of realism that actual practicing realists (and anyone that cares about agreeing with observations) do not believe in. You can call it straw man realism since it exists just to be disproven.

The idea is that you want realism and you want your realism to satisfy a bunch of things that are unreasonable to expect. So here is the straw man realism.

- That "measurements" reveal a property that already exists
- That a "component" of a spin is a property that can be revealed by a measurement
- That the result of the "measurement" should depend on the orientation of the device and the state of thing being "measured" and not on anything else
- That the orientation selection is assigned in a way not related to whatever makes results be preassigned to orientations.

In short, the idea is that you imagine that a spin or polarization is a function from an orientation to a result in the spectrum of the corresponding operator.  This is provably wrong even with one particle.

For instance if you have something that is spin up for the z direction is has a **real** property one that can be observed in the lab. The real property is that if it goes through a Stern-Gerlach orientated in the z axis then it always and repeatably come out the same side when sent through the device again and again and always comes out the same for similarly calibrated devices (for instance ones whose fields point in the direction and get stronger in as you move in the z direction that kind of calibration).

But when you measure the "x component" of the spin you clearly destroy that real property that can be observed in the lab. So the so called measurements are obviously polarizations that change the state unless already in an eigenstate.

So what they are assuming is that the particles "have" a preexisting result for every orientation of "measurement" device and that the device should reveal it.

Now some people will object to me saying this straw man realism is a state man. They might say this is exactly what realism should be. But they are wrong and you can tell by looking at an actual realist theory designed to agree with observation.

So for instance the realist should have some thing that has a well defined property, our thing can be the wavefunction itself including the spin state and if you want we can also through in that there is a position of exactly that type of realism that position measurements reveal something about the position without changing it etcetera.

If you do this you can now stop and have a fully realistic theory that agrees with observations, including so called spin "measurements." What does such a theory say about spin measurements?

Such a theory says that since you could throw a position detector inside any other device including a Stern-Gerlach device and in any portion of the Stern-Gerlach device that we are forced to accurately model how position changes within a Stern-Gerlach device. Because nature doesn't know if you intended the Stern-Gerlach device to be a holder for your position detectors.

In general, nature doesn't care about your feelings regarding the Stern-Gerlach device. It just cares about how things evolve. How does position evolve inside a Stern-Gerlach device? It depends on the calibration, because some devices send the spin up beams up and some actually send them down but both work just as well because they consistently deflect spin up one way and spin down the other way and the point of a Stern-Gerlach is to deflect beams of different spin in different directions in a consistent manner.

OK, so how does it work? You just write down the Hamiltonian for the actual experimental setup, we know the Hamiltonian for a particle with a magnetic moment in an inhomogeneous external magnetic field. So based on the magnetic field of the actual Stern-Gerlach device you write down the Hamiltonian and then evolve the incoming beam according to the Schrödinger equation.

You see that spin up beams are deflected one way. You see that spin down beams are deflected the other way. You see that a beam with a different spin state becomes spatially split like a river forking around an island in the middle of it. And that each branch has the spin in that branch become polarized to become up or down depending on which way the branch went.

And no other option was available since you might pit a position detector at any place inside or next to or beyond the Stern-Gerlach device.

So now if you take a realist view of position and sent an eigenstate of $\sigma_x$ into a z oriented Stern-Gerlach device you can track how positions change and you see that whether it becomes spin up or spin down is 100% determined by the *position* of the particle.

Which means the same particle with the same spin and same spatial wavefunction and same hidden position will become spin up or spin down depending on how it's position is related to the **calibration** of the Stern-Gerlach device.  Imagine the beams as a river carrying the realist position along in time and if the position is on a particular side of the river when it spatially splits then it ends up there and it's spin gets polarized that way. And if it were in the other side then the spin becomes polarized the other way.

This contradicts the straw man realism where the spin is result you get us only supposed to depend on the spin state and he orientation o the Stern-Gerlach device. The straw man version forbids you from having the orientation be controlled by the realist positions it forbids the resulting spin polarization from depending on the realist positions and it forbids the resulting spin polarization from depending on your choice of which kind of calibrated Stern-Gerlach device you choose to use (and forbids the realist position from determining which you choose and so on and so on the Straw man wants it to depend on just the orientation and the spin state).

Now a calibration of a Stern-Gerlach device does not change the relative size of the two split beams. The relative size of them is always proportional to the relative sizes of the squares of the projections onto the eigenvalues (and yes you get that from just the Schrödinger equation, no Born needed). Just if some incoming beam is more spin up than spin down, then the bigger beam could go up or could go down (depending on the calibration of the device) just so long as the bigger beam goes the way spin up is sent by the device.

So if all you care about is the frequencies these differently calibrated devices are just as good. But they do turn different realist things into different actual things. It's like the non realists are color blind. There are simply things that look just the same to them but they are different.

And they really are different because they create different correlations between spin and position becsuse that is what a Stern-Gerlach device does. It correlates a particle's own spin with its own position by polarizing the spin differently along the two different paths it creates.

So this is all just one particle. And that strawman realism is wrong. A spin "measurement" is really (i.e. what we do in the lab is) a polarization process that creates beams of different sizes (based on the relative size of the square of the projections onto eigenspaces) and polarizes the spin depending on which part of the beam it is and that correlates the spin and the position in a way that is unrelated to how it can make different beams have the right sizes and be polarized correctly in the right sized part.

That's what we really do and a realist for position has to agree with that becsuse that is just describing how the wavefunction evolved for the actual experimental set up so it has to get the magnitude and current correct at any time and place (if it is realist about position).

So that is one particle. The same thing happens for more particles. Just write down the actual Hamiltonian for the actual set up and evolve it. When the spins are entangled you still see the beams be the right size you still see them widen and split as they progress except now it happens in configuration space.

But you have to have the wave be nonzero at the right places in configuration space if you are a realist about position so it all had to be a dynamic evolution in configuration space to begin with. I don't see how you can specify certain initial conditions if you want to be local.

But these analysis you ask about were not made by practicing realists. So they use a straw man realism and then try to put localism and have it not depend on calibration and to forbid superdeterminism all just so they can vague up the class of theories they want to exclude. And the ones they exclude are not the ones realists use.

They just want to be able to say thing like what if the result of this one depends on the orientation here and not on the orientation there. When for just one particle we already know the result depends on which calibration you choose and on the position. So no realist would say that.

And Bell is right that theories like that are wrong. But theories like that were wrong just because having it depend on just the orientation already gives the wrong correlations between position and spin on just one particle.

> Thanks. So the straw man realism is rejected. But let's assume entangled photons with "real" polarization of 0° and 90°. The 0° photon will always pass a 0° filter, the 90° will always fail, but the 0° one will pass a 45° only half of the time - whenever the 90° doesn't pass 45°. So why not say that on creation the first one gets the plan 45°=>pass, the second one gets the opposite -45°=>fail, but this plan gets randomly swapped as a result of another function?

I will discuss the spin 1/2 version because it's easier for me, I hope there isn't anything essentially different.

There are some problems.

First you can't just lay down "plans" when things are created because entanglement can be swapped.

Second we already know exactly what happens. If you measure spin up with a certain device it gets deflected up and so down is deflected down and so an eigenstate of $\sigma_x$ has the beam get split exactly in half. And the upper half goes up and the lower half goes down. And the spin states become eigenstates of $\sigma_z.$ There is no freedom there is no choice this is what the Schrödinger equation says and we see this happen in the lab by putting particle detectors **inside** the Stern-Gerlach instead of just on the two ends where the beams get deflected. By moving the particle detectors around to various locations we verify that that wave evolves exactly like the Schrödinger equation says it does.

So this is not opinion and it is not speculation it is what happens. An eigenstate of \sigma_x$ gets spilt into two and it is the upper half that becomes spin up and the lower half that becomes spin down.

Let's see what happens if they were entangled to have opposite spins.  Let y be the up/down **position** for particle 1 and let x be the up/down **position** for particle 2 then initially the beam is a state that look like a square spatially and has a spin state like $\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right\rangle+\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right\rangle$ now if we send particle 1 through a Stern-Gerlach we know that the beam widens as it approaches the fork and branches. So the square itself gets taller and then a horizontal line forms when it gets as large as two squares and then it splits into one square going up and one square going down.  That's simply what the configuration space looks like if one beam separates spatially and the other doesn't.  Bit the spin state is now $\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right\rangle$ in that upper square and is $\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right\rangle$ in the lower square.

Great, now what happens when you send particle 2 through a Stern-Gerlach. That will send the lower square to the right and send the upper square to the left with no splitting.

That is what a Stern-Gerlach oriented in the direction $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ does. It deflects beams that are eigen to $n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z$ and splits the others into two beams such that the relative sizes are equal to the relative sizes of its projections onto the eigenspaces of $n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z.$ sending one beam one way and the other beam the other and continuously polarizes the spin to become the eigenstate associated with that direction.

So the second one used just deflects. If you ran them through in the other order then first the square gets wider then a vertical line forms and the two squares split.  At this point the spin has changed to be $\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right\rangle$ in that left square and is $\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right\rangle$ in the right square.
And then the left square gets deflected up as the right square gets deflected down.

This is all just what the Schrödinger equation says and we have no choice. So we know exactly what determines the outcome and it isn't local and it doesn't just depend on the spin state and the orientation of the device. Because the Schrödinger says that isn't what it depends on.

And if you tried to lay plans at creation then you'd have to say how you swap the plans. And it wouldn't matter because when the Stern-Gerlach devices were pulled out they would have to evolve how I said, and not how you planned. Because I'm just using the Schrödinger equation and we can measure that in the lab.

OK. If you like filters you could have one of the squares move in the third dimension to signify how the thing that absorbs a state gets itself changed. But the story is the same. We know exactly how spin happens because our measurement devices always change the position state, they are local devices that fit into a small region that is of course how they work how they must work.

There isn't room for you or Mermin or Bell or anyone to tell us what we might do or could do (or even can't do) to get the results we know what does happen to get the results.

**That said, you actually might be trying to describe exactly what I'm saying.** I am merely emphasizing clearly what it has to be based on indisputable already known things. So for instance if you have a three particle state then you can have an initial cube of spatial configuration and it can still grow and split when you put anything through a Stern Gerlach and the spin states will still just separate out based on which particle needs to have its spin become eigen. You just project the joint spin state onto the space of states that have that particle be eigen to $n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z$ for the device oriented like $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ And then all the cubes grow in that direction and split into things of the right size compared to those projections and each ends with a spin state that is that projection.  And that is because this is what the Schrödinger equation predicts.

So knowing the $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ for each device and knowing the order we do them and knowing the initial joint spin state we can see exactly how that cube and spin state change and become entangled.

So could just be not licking with the words you use such as "created" when it is just a function of the $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ for each device and knowing the order we do them and knowing the initial joint spin state and then we know enough to see which part of the cube ends up in which final position. And each of these disjoint cubes has a spin state that is a simple product of single particle spin states each of which is eigen to the $n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z$ for the $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ for its device.

So people make their own assumptions becsuse there purpose is to destroy a straw man. If you want to understand what happens we know what happens. And I've tried to spell it out, but I should probably just hire a production crew to make videos that just show it.

Comment: I will comment as I read: No, I don't think that a measurement reveals the previously unknown spin. The measurement's result depends on the "real" spin, yes, but is really a filter and therefore changes that spin and due to the probabilistic nature the result cannot be used to tell what the "real" spin was. Only lots of measurements (of theoretically identical photons) would give us an idea of the "real" spin.

Comment: @xnor You asked about the static plan. The static plan is based a straw man version of realism that *no one* today thinks is correct. I'm not saying you think it is correct. I'm saying Bell isn't about making a good realist theory it is about showing that certain theories that we already knew were wrong are still wrong. All the other kinds of realism can still be right.

Comment: Thanks. So the straw man realism is rejected. But let's assume entangled photons with "real" polarization of 0° and 90°. The 0° photon will always pass a 0° filter, the 90° will always fail, but the 0° one will pass a 45° only half of the time - whenever the 90° doesn't pass 45°. So why not say that on creation the first one gets the plan 45°=>pass, the second one gets the opposite -45°=>fail, but this plan gets randomly swapped as a result of another function?

Comment: @xnor I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

To see what the issue is, it pays to think about an exaggerated example.

Suppose two photons arrive at locations 1 and 2.   Then you (at location 1) and I (at location 2) perform either of two experiments, A or B.

And suppose each photon has a built-in probability of being measured red when experiment A is performed, and some other built-in probability of being measured green when experiment B is performed.

And suppose these four things happen:

1. Whenever you and I both perform experiment A, we always get the same result.
2. Whenever you perform experiment A and I perform experiment B, we always get the same result.
3. Whenever you perform experiment B and I perform experiment A, we always get the same result.
4. Whenever you and I both perform experiment B, we always get opposite results.

Now I claim that if you believe each photon has some "built-in" probability of registering red when experiment A is performed, and some other "built-in" probability of registering green when experiment B is performed, and if those probabilities do not depend on what's happening at a distant location, then it is impossible (using the standard assumptions of probability theory) to explain all four of these results.

Try it!  Try assigning probabilities any way you want to, and you will find that you make the wrong prediction for at least one of these four experiments.

Now what actually happens in quantum mechanics is a bit subtler than the fictional experimental outcomes I've described here, but the issues are exactly the same.  The (experimentally verified!) predictions of quantum mechanics cannot all be simultaneously consistent with *any* probabilities that could have been assigned in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in QM either.

Comment: @xnor:  If you want a more realistic example consistent with QM, change "always" to "about 85% of the time" in #2,3,and 4.  But it might be easier for you to understand the fundamental issue if you first think about the simpler and easier example above.

Comment: That still doesn't appear to work. Can't you change this to a real example using entangled photons with unknown linear but opposite (90°) polarization and A and B being linear polarization filters with angles of your choice?

Comment: @xnor:  With the 85% numbers from my last comment, this is exactly the real example you just requested.   Take the photons to be in the state $R\otimes R+G\otimes G$ and compute.

Comment: Btw, I'm not saying these particles have some built-in probabilities. I'm saying that the particles get a random "plan" whose rules match the expected probabilities on average, and entangled photons always get the opposite "plan".

Comment: If you say your example works then why wouldn't it work with my suggestion?
The main thing that looks off in your example is that we measure entangled photons identically (case 4) but don't always get opposite results.

Comment: @xnor:  As I said, work out the case of $R\otimes R+G\otimes G$, where the measurements at $A$ are at angles of $0$ and $\pi/4$, and the measurements at $B$ are at angles of $\pi/8$ and $3\pi/8$.  I have no idea what you mean by your "suggestion".

Comment: I don't understand. If you measure at A first 0° and then 45° the probabilities are `1/2 cos(45°)^2 = 1/4` for green, so you won't get always red.

Comment: The probability for red is in fact always 50% for any of the four measurements (as you can see immediately from the symmetry of the state).

Comment: Sure, if you look at each measurement in isolation. But if an entangled photon reaches me, and it passes the 0° test (50% probability) then yours will fail, right? So if my photon is then polarized, the probability of passing the second part of test A is cos(pi/4)^2, so there is a remaining 50% chance that I will see green. So in a few cases we won't get the same result if we both perform A, but that is what you said in your example.

Comment: @xnor:  I have no idea what "passes the 0 degree test" means.  I have no idea what "the second part of test A" means.  If you work out the math, you'll see what's going on.  If you don't, you won't.

Comment: PS --- Here, I suspect, is the root of your confusion:  You seem to persist in thinking that Prob(red) and Prob(green) are the  interesting numbers here.  They're not.  The interesting numbers are Prob(same) and Prob(different).

Comment: One "measurement" is a linear polarization filter rotated by some angle. "Passing 0°" means that the photon goes through such a filter that is rotated by 0°, i.e. horizontal.
Now you said A consists of 2 of such measurements: 0° and 45°, so two consecutive polarization filters. If you send entangled photons to two people doing A, the result does not match what you stated in your example.